# How to keep form in original state if i change and revert the values in angular2?

Tags: forms, angular

I have one form which I open from web app when I want to edit my page. 

If I'm not changing any value and submitting the form then my page should remain in its original state but it is changing the state. 

To avoid this, I have used pristine property. But if I change the value from old to new then again from new to old then pristine is not working.

What could be the better solution to handle form in Angular 2?

```
<button class="button large w100 primary" type="button" (click)="submitEntry(timecardForm.pristine)">
    <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> {{ 'global.apply' | translate }}
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this case once.

What I did (I was using reactive forms but you can use whatever you want) is that when the user entered the page, I fetched all the form data, then stored it like this

```
let initialFormValue = JSON.stringify(this.myForm.value);
```

Then the user could change everything he wants. When he wanted to leave the page (in your case, cancel form submission), all that was left was to compare the two strings. This would give

```
let actualFormValue = JSON.stringify(this.myForm.value);
if (this.initialFormValue === actualFormValue) { /* alert the user */ }
```

I hope this helps. If not, feel free to ask !

Comment: Thanks for the solution. By this implementation it is not reading the value from radio buttons or checkbox values. Also where exactly i can implement this kind of change where i can mention for initial value and actual value ?

Comment: As I told you I used reactive forms. What you can do if you don't, is to create an object containing all of your data.  You store the initial value once you have loaded the user information, and you make the comparison in the method called when you submit your form